# Echoing HTML To create elements

Tags: php

For some reason this wont work, i think i have it right because i did read up about this:

```
echo '<li class="dropdown">';
echo    '<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-close-others="false" data-delay="0" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">';
echo        '<img src="<?=$steamprofile['avatar']?>" height="30" style="border-radius: 100%;">';
echo    '</a>';
echo '</li>';
```

What is my error? i mean i dont really see what is wrong with it i have done it before and it worked?

Comment: I think the problem are the quotes. Maybe you are mixing single and double quotes wrongly.

Comment: Your problem is here `'<img src="<?=$steamprofile['avatar`. It'll also be obvious if you enable debugging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: Agreed @SergiuParaschiv.

Comment: `echo        '<img src="<?=$steamprofile['avatar']?>"` ... it doesn't even make sense .. all else aside that's attempting to run into PHP and echo a variable when already in PHP and echoing *... choing ... ing ... ng*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
echo '<li class="dropdown">';
echo '<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-close-others="false" data-delay="0" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">';
echo '<img src="'.$steamprofile['avatar'].'" height="30" style="border-radius: 100%;">';
echo '</a>';
echo '</li>';
```

Comment: I missed concatenation

Answer (score 3):

Don't use apostrophes ([single quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)) when you want to interpolate variables into strings, `$` will be literally interpreted as `$` **not** the start of a variable.

Use either [double quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) (escaping the double quotes within):

```
echo "<li class=\"dropdown\">"
    . "<a class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-close-others=\"false\" data-delay=\"0\" data-hover=\"dropdown\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" href=\"#\">"
    . "<img src=\"{$steamprofile['avatar']}\" height=\"30\" style=\"border-radius: 100%;\">"
    . "</a>"
    . "</li>";
```

Or [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax:

```
echo <<<EOT
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-close-others="false" data-delay="0" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
<img src="{$steamprofile['avatar']}" height="30" style="border-radius: 100%;">
</a>
</li>
EOT;
```

Comment: Actually it's a lot neater that within HTML elements you can use single quotes within the PHP double quoted string. `... data-close-others='false' data-delay='0' ... ` etc.

Comment: And apostraphes are in this case also often known as *single quotes* :-)

Comment: Yeah - I know - I just *prefer* to see double quotes in the HTML when I view source :)

Comment: hahaha, each to their own. Escaped double quotes in a double quote encased PHP string makes me cross-eyed :-(

Comment: in that case `HEREDOC` wins then :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easier to simply drop out of php parsing and output straight html. There isn't any measureable performance hit in doing this and often the code is much more readable.

```
?> //if needed, drop out of PHP parsing

<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-close-others="false" data-delay="0" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
```

Echo only the vars needed within the html.

```
    <img src="<?= $steamprofile['avatar']; ?>" height="30" style="border-radius: 100%;">
  </a>
</li>

<?php //continue with PHP parsing (if needed)
```